# Why showing undefined service and aliases in app file in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

I am using **laravel 5.1.** Some files in service and aliases are showing undefined. I don't know what goes wrong here. It is showing this....[image]

and also in aliases..
[image]

I am new in laravel. I don't know what happened there. Any kinds of help will be appreciated.Thanks

Comment: Is laravel actually installed? Have you got a vendor/laravel folder in your root?

Comment: yes i have worked a lot of this files. I try make:auth command from terminal although i have already authentication files. After running  this command . This is showing but what may goes wrong from here  do you think?

Comment: yes i have vendor/laravel file

Answer (score 0):

Try using this package: [Laravel 5 IDE Helper Generator](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper)

This package generates a IDE helper to help your IDE. Take a look if this help you.

Regards